# counting number of hops

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, graph-algorithm

I have below table:

orig dest

100  200

101  201

200  300

In this case, the distance(or hops) from orig 100 to dest 300 is 2. To elaborate, the graph path is 100>200>300 which is 2 hop.

I have created a scipy sparse matrix like below and got my BFS order like below:
`[100,200,300]` when I provide scipy.sparse.csgraph.breadth_first_order with i_start value as 100.

However, I need the hop count array. Is there any option to do that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are getting `[100, 200, 300]` as a response, which seems to be OK. Can't you do `len(response[1:])` to get the number of hops?

Comment: are those numbers representing three single-digit indices or three digit numbers?  If you are treating every digit separately then try splitting up the number into the digits: `digits = [int(digit) for digit in str(number)]` or similar, then I think the "hops" would be something like `sum(abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(orig_digits, dest_digits))` although this specific code will only work if the two numbers have the same number of digits

Answer (score 1):

## Counting hops

I put the data into a string called hop. And then I counted the hop (100=1) as I think I understood.

```
hop = """100 200
101 201
200 300"""

hop = hop.split("\n")

hcnt = 0
for h in hop:
    o, d = int(h.split()[0]), int(h. split()[1])
    dist = ((d - o) / 100)
    hcnt += dist

print("hops:", hcnt)
```

## output

```
hops: 3.0
```